# how to check if all of a vector values are equal to a determined value

Tags: c++, if-statement, vector, error-handling

I have this code:

```
int generatore(std::vector<bool> vettore, int *x) {
    int y;
    
    if (std::adjacent_find(vettore.begin(), vettore.end(), std::not_equal_to<>()) == vettore.end() {
        return *x + 1;
    }
    else {
        do {
            y = rand() % *x;
        } while (vettore.at(y) == true);

        return y;
    }
}
```

What this function does is basically get a **vector** that stores boolean values that say if the indexes have already been used and its **size**, when it is called it should return an index from the ones that hadn't been used or ***x+1** if all of them had been.
The vector used as parameter will never be empty.
A **false** value would mean that that index hasn't been used, the problem with this code is that if all of the values are equal to false it returns *x+1 instead of choosing one random index, so i should only check if all the values are **equal to true**, what should i change?

Comment: You have a typo. In the comparison `== vettore.end` should be `== vettore.end()`.

Comment: oh, thanks , that was so dumb of me to not notice... i have another problem that i wrote in the edit, could you lookif you can help me with that aswell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` condition already checks whether all the values in the vector are the same, so you could check if the first element is also the one you want:

```
if (vettore.front() == false   // add this
    && std::adjacent_find(vettore.begin(), vettore.end(), std::not_equal_to<>()) == vettore.end()) { 
  // ...
}
```

Doing this check before the `adjacent_find` lets the evaluation of the algorithm be potentially avoided.

You could also use the `all_of` algorithm:

```
if (std::all_of(vettore.begin(), vettore.end(), [](auto b) { return !b; })) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: `std::all_of` takes a predicate, not a value. In your first example, I'd probably do the equality test first just to short-circuit calling the algorithm.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Oops, that was careless. Thanks for catching that. Clearly OP only tried the first solution before accepting :/ Oh, yeah, good point about swapping the check in the first solution.